# What is an elegant way to order a list of time (hh:mm:ss) to a ordered one?

Tags: python, string, list, time

I have a long list of time, in the format of `hh:mm:ss` and want to order them. For simplicity suppose the given list is the following

`l=['07:35:00','01:51:00','04:38:00','09:31:00','12:40:00','06:30:00','12:02:00','04:20:00','02:33:00']` 
how can I get this in order using some modules or a code snippet that does this and is simpler than my code?

Answer: `['1:51:0','2:33:0','4:20:0','4:38:0','6:30:0','7:35:0','9:31:0','12:2:0','12:40:0']`

My try:
I wrote the following function which does it:

```py
def time_sorting(l):
    t = [ list(map(int, i.split(':')))  for i in l ] 
    a = np.asarray(t)
    h = a[np.argsort(a[:,0])]
    a[np.argsort(a[:,0])]
    t_l = list()
    for i in range(24):
        t_l.extend( h[ h[:, 0] == i] [np.argsort(h[ h[:, 0] == i ][:,1]) ].tolist() )
    t_f = [':'.join(list(map(str,i))) for i in t_l]    
    return t_f
```

Also, I have other issue which is loosing zeros. Please help me with that as well to keep zeros as they were.

Comment: If all times are really in `HH:MM:SS`, then all you need to do is `l.sort()`.

Comment: `time_sorting = sorted`

Comment: @accdias: that works!!!. Please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all times are really in `HH:MM:SS` format, then all you need is `sort()`. Check it out:

```py
>>> # pprint is just for a nicely formatted output
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> times = [
...    '07:35:00',
...    '01:51:00',
...    '04:38:00',
...    '09:31:00',
...    '12:40:00',
...    '06:30:00',
...    '12:02:00',
...    '04:20:00',
...    '02:33:00'
... ]  
>>>               
>>> times.sort()
>>> pprint(times)
['01:51:00',
 '02:33:00',
 '04:20:00',
 '04:38:00',
 '06:30:00',
 '07:35:00',
 '09:31:00',
 '12:02:00',
 '12:40:00']
>>>
```

I hope it helps.